# Why does the current and gm of this MOSFET not follow their correspondent formula

Tags: mosfet

So M1 is a 32nm tech MOSFET where its parameters are taken from nanohub (Resource: Tools: Nano_CMOS) and then included in LTspice. The first image has a transistor named M1 with L= 36nm and W=72nm.

Knowing that the current that passes through the drain is given by:

Id = K * (vgs - vt)^2

I should expect a quadratic curve for Id(M1) and a linear curve for gm (d(Id(M1)) but that's not what happens in the image below.

[image]

Any idea why this happens? I reckon that for this model Id must be equal to K * (vgs - vt)^1.5 or something like that to make that happen.

Then i keep changing V1 from 0 to 1V and compare the current Id for different Vgs:

[image]

What i can say here is that the bigger the Vgs values get the bigger the drain current gets, that goes with the first equation i put here. I see nothing wrong here.

Then i did the same procedure as before but with a different W(144nm) and L(72nm):

[image]

For example when Vgs is 0.8V, i get Id around 70uA in the first case and 100uA in the second case with a different W and L. That shouldnt happen because the W/L ratio is the same in both cases, why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 32nm technology will not follow the square law anymore.

As the length of the channel decreases, the field established between the source and drain becomes very high near the drain (as drain voltage increases). This causes velocity saturation and mobility degradation thus decreasing the overall current. Here, it is observed that the relation between drain current and overdrive voltage is more linear. An empirical relation for mobility dependence on electric field is given as
$$
\mu_{eff} = A{E_{eff}}^{-1/3}
$$
This is empirically derived where A is a constant dependent on doping. There can be other relations between mobility and transverse electric field as well.

There are other things as well that effects the current but I am not quite sure as to if those are modeled in the technology that you chose. To read more on mobility, you can read the Wikipedia article and proceed from there. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_mobility#:~:text=Usually%2C%20the%20electron%20drift%20velocity,depends%20on%20the%20electric%20field.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_mobility#:%7E:text=Usually%2C%20the%20electron%20drift%20velocity,depends%20on%20the%20electric%20field.)

You can also view Field Effect Devices by Robert F. Pierret from the modular series on solid state devices to know more about mobility degradation and other small dimension effects.

Answer (score 2):

FETs in advanced technologies (esp. below 130 nm) don't follow the square law particularly well. This is because of velocity saturation, and other mobility reduction effects.

Comment: Where can i know about more of this velocity saturation, and other mobility reduction effects for tech bellow 130nm ?